# How to extend from a generic class?

Tags: typescript

Now I have three classes, `A`, `B` and `C`.

`B` extends from `A`. `C` may extend from `A` or from `B`.

How do I code for the class C?

Is there anything like:

```
class C extends <T>{...}
```

`T` will only be `A` or `B`. Whether it is `A` or `B` is decided in compile time.

Comment: Is it decided at runtime whether C extends A or B? Is it possible just to make two versions of C, one that extends A and the other that extends B? Then you can just construct the right one based on your runtime constraints.

Comment: It would also help if you gave an example of how you want to use `C` - one example of when you want to use `C` where it extends `B`, and another example of using `C` where it extends `A`.

Comment: Basically, you cannot do this. Why do you want to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anything like `class C extends <T>{...}`

No there isn't.

You can create `CA extends A` and `CB extends CB` and choose between the two at runtime

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with generics. You can do that using a pattern similar to [mixin classes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743), but it's rather involved and requires you to describe what class `C` would add to `A` or `B` in a separate interface, and then to have a function that constructs and returns class definition using A or B as parameter. You also have to provide 2 separate overload declarations for that function because basically it's impossible to declare class that extends anything other than a class - you could not use union type `A | B` for that.

```
class A { a: string }

class B extends A { b: string }

interface C_only { // decsribes what C will add to either A or B
    c: number;
}

interface C_extended_from_A {
    new (): C_only & A;
}
interface C_extended_from_B {
    new (): C_only & B;
}

function extend_A_or_B(Base: typeof B): C_extended_from_B;
function extend_A_or_B(Base: typeof A): C_extended_from_A;
function extend_A_or_B(Base: typeof A): typeof A {
    return class C extends Base implements C_only {
        constructor() {
            super();
    // can access only methods from common base class A in the implementation
            this.c = this.a.length;
        }

        c: number;
    }
}

const CA = extend_A_or_B(A);
const CB = extend_A_or_B(B);

const ca = new CA();
const cb = new CB();


const a1 = ca.a;
//const b1 = ca.b // error - no b here 
const c1 = ca.c;

const a2 = cb.a;
const b2 = cb.b;
const c2 = cb.c;
```

Not sure if it solves your problem, or if it's worth to have such complexity, but here it is.